# Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object only in some phones

Tags: java, android, crash, parcelable

I have this exception in my project in Fragment.java and I don't know what is the problem, because I've already implement Parcelable for MyClass class and should not be a problem with it.
Am I missing something?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = mypackage.a.a.a)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1447)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1395)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:665)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1337)
   at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:690)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:148)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1233)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:564)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1416)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1322)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:665)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1337)
   at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:690)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:150)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1233)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:564)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1416)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1322)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:665)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1337)
   at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079)
   at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:690)
   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3153)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3455)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5621)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
```

> Caused by java.io.NotSerializableException mypackage.model.MyClass

and here is `MyClass` code:

```
public class MyClass implements Parcelable {

    private transient JSONObject json;
    public static final String KEY = "my_key";
    public static final String VALUE = "my_value";

    public MyClass(){
        json = new JSONObject();
    }

    public MyClass(String json){
        try {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(json)) {
                json = new JSONObject(json);
            }else {
                json = new JSONObject();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public MyClass myMethod1(String s1, String s2){
        //Do something here
    }

    public String myMethod2(String s1){
        //Do something here
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return json.toString();
    }

    public String jsonText() {
        return json.toString();
    }


    protected MyClass(Parcel in) {
        try {
            json = in.readByte() == 0x00 ? null : new JSONObject(in.readString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        if (json == null) {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
        } else {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
            dest.writeString(json.toString());
        }
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyClass> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyClass>() {
        @Override
        public MyClass createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyClass(in);
        }

        @Override
        public MyClass[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyClass[size];
        }
    };

    public static MyClass myMethod3(){
        //Do something here
    }
}
```

I have removed the body of methods for make it shorter to review. I'm passing this object with Intent between my activities and my code is working on many phones, but this exception only occurs in some phones, not all of them.

Comment: On the face of it, the problem is that your class doesn't implement `Serializable`.

Comment: @StephenC should I implement Both Serializable and Parcelable together?

Comment: I am guessing yes.  Try it.

Comment: @StephenC Then there will be an ambiguity in intent.putExtra(), it doesn't know use Serializable or Parcelable.

Comment: I don't know.  Have you tried it?

Comment: then probably point it as `(Parcelable) yourObject`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko
Why it should implement both Parcelable and Serializable together, So where is the benefits of Parcelable?

Comment: @StephenC Yes, and it said there is an ambiguity.

Comment: And did the typecast solve it?

Comment: In general there is no need to do that (implement both), but Android platform is too free to modify in some cases. I think you have never worked with the bluetooth in ANdorid. It is almost each manufacturar's custom implementation everywhere for bluetooth.  I mean that sometimes we are forced to use such workarounds, and this is probably the case.

Comment: @StephenC It solved the ambiguity, But now I have a problem with implementing both Serializable and Parcelable together, it doesn't make sense to me actually.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko What is your idea about using Serializable only, and changing the JSONObject to String to hold the Json text and remove the parcelable codes? Because JSONObject is not serializable.

Comment: Judging from the stacktrace, the parcel code is using serialization, and is encountering a `MyClass` instance as a component of something else.  Given that, does `MyClass` need to be parcelable?

Comment: @StephenC I just use Parcelable because it is faster than serializable and actually it is an android specific implementation.

Comment: I asked: does it **need** to be parcelable?   Because it looks like when you parcelled the object that indirectly refers to the `MyClass` instance, it was trying to use object serialization!